# Set Increment Number or Index Value in a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm having a Collection of type **`Mobile`**

```
public class Mobile
{
    public string MobileName { get; set; }
    public string MobileOS { get; set; }
}

ObservableCollection<Mobile> MobileList = new ObservableCollection<Mobile>()
{
    new Mobile() { MobileName = "iPhone 6", MobileOS = "IOS" },
    new Mobile() { MobileName = "Galaxy S6", MobileOS = "Android" },
    new Mobile() { MobileName = "Lumina", MobileOS = "Windows" },
}
```

The appropriate WPF `DataGrid` (XAML)

```
<DataGrid Name="Grid1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding MobileList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <!--Column 1-->
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="" Header="Index" />
        <!--Column 2-->
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MobileName}" Header="Name" />
        <!--Column 3-->
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MobileOS}" Header="OS" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I need to set the Index value in **Column 1**. Kindly assist me how to set the index value for the column which is associated with the collection.

> **Note**: I need this in XAML Level not in C# Code Level Implementation

**Required Data Grid : Model Snapshot**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a custom column for this purpose just add [`LoadingRow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.loadingrow(v=vs.110).aspx) event to your `DataGrid` and remove `<DataGridTextColumn  Header="Index" />`:

```
<DataGrid Name="Grid1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" LoadingRow="Grid1_OnLoadingRow">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MobileName}" Header="Name" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MobileOS}" Header="OS" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Then:

```
private void Grid1_OnLoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Header = (e.Row.GetIndex()).ToString();
}
```

Comment: can you please add the Full XAML Code please.

Comment: @IRPunch See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please explain me. how to access the row number in datatrigger ? For example I need to change the color of the text if the row number is 2. How could I identify the property ?